# Voltage regulator circuit

Tags: inductor, linear-regulator, ceramic, ferrite-bead

I am using [this linear regulator](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP2204.pdf) and the application circuit looks like this:

[image: application ckt]

Is the above circuit good enough?

I have a habit of putting a series ferrite bead on the input side but after reading a couple of answers about the topic, I feel that ferrite bead is not useful for such cases.

In most of the cases, the Vin will come from a ac to DC offline switching power supply which work around 100 kHz switching frequency.

1) Does it make sense to use a series ferrite bead or an inductor at the input side?

2) Is 1 uF and 2.2 uF capacitor good enough or should I increase the values? My load will be an MCU drawing roughly 10 mA and RF module drawing 50 mA during transmits.

3) To manage my inventory well, is it acceptable if I purchase 50 V rated X5R ceramic capacitors and use the same for all voltage ranges up to 24 VDC? Is ceramic capacitors good for this purpose?

Comment: *I feel that ferrite bead is not useful for such cases.* I would agree. Ferrite beads only "do something" above 100 MHz or so. If you're concerned about RF signals then add a 1 nF ceramic capacitor in parallel with **each** cap in this circuit. If your product has no RF signals then that's not needed either.

Comment: What is the maximum **input** voltage to the regulator? Are you saying it can be up to 24V?

Comment: Vin can be up to 24V but in my case, I will be using 12V max.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're **overthinking** this too much.

> My load will be an MCU drawing roughly 10 mA and RF module drawing 50 mA during transmits.

MCUs genereally **don't care much** about (ripply and noise) on their supply lines. Heck, these digital circuits are generally the ones that **pollute** the supply lines!

No, you do not need ferrite beads and/or inductors in your supply lines. That only applies for **sensitive circuits** when also RF (high frequencies) is involved.

Just follow the general rules:

- add a supply decoupling capacitor (100 nF) between the supply pin of each chip and ground.
- if possible use a large ground plane
- add input and output capacitors as the manufacturer on an LDO suggests. The manufacturer of the AP2204 suggets 1uF and 2.2 uF so that's what you will use.
- use ceramic capacitors unless these are too large and/or too expensive. 2.2 uF is fine for a ceramic cap.
- If you need to use a non-ceramic capacitor for decoupling, add a 100 nF ceramic cap **in parallel** with it to improve high frequency behavior.

X5R ceramic capacitors are "good enough" if you use them for hobby projects. For professional use you might need X7R which are "better" but more expensive.

In general: if you're just playing with a micro controller for hobby purposes and nothing high frequency is involved then almost any capacitor will do the job. There is also no need to use inductors and ferrite beads.

Also: see what others do and do the same, there are plenty of microcontroller based designs / projects to be found. For example the many Arduino based projects, just copy what they do and notice how they generally don't use any inductors nor worry about the capacitors.